# Creating a Custom Toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a Project in Visual Studio which includes some UserControl files.  I created some custom toolboxes (we'll call it the scroll bar) that I manually put into the UserControl code, where most of the code is compiler generated. So if I change the layout of the UserControl using the Designer, the code behind gets changed and my scroll bar does not show up anymore. I've found a way to address this via [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSControlInToolbox.aspx).

But now the problem I am having is I want to relate a Windows checkbox to my scroll bar such that if the checkBox is unchecked, I want to hide the scroll bar. If it is checked, I want it to show up.

Is there a way to accomplish this without manipulating the compiler generated code? I am able to do this by changing the code but as I've noted, if I change the UserControl from the designer, I lose all my custom changed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: would it be correct when I say that on the designer I'll have all the buttons (including the initially hidden ones) set up but in the other partial class, I'll reassign the coordinates of the buttons during run time?

Comment: Without seeing your project, that sounds like a reasonable assumption to me.